# navigation and how to register the view with the region?

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I have two views between which I want to navigate on button click and they are  registered with a region on module initialization like this:

```
public class ModuleTaxCalc : IModule //PRISM MODULE POWER
{
    IUnityContainer container;
    IRegionManager regionManager;


    public ModuleTaxCalc(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager)
    {
        this.container = container;
        this.regionManager = regionManager;

    }

    public void Initialize()
    {

        container.RegisterType<ICustomer, Customer>();

        //container.RegisterType<object, ViewA>("ViewA");
        //container.RegisterType<object, ViewB>("ViewB");
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TaxCalculatorRegion", typeof(ViewA));
        regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("TaxCalculatorRegion", typeof(ViewB));

    }


}
```

My issue is that the 'ViewA' gets visible automatically when application starts/

if I do this instead:

```
 public void Initialize()
        {

            container.RegisterType<object, ViewA>("ViewA");
            container.RegisterType<object, ViewB>("ViewB");


        }
```

then both views are invisible and become visible only on button click, but I guess they are not registered with the region in this case.

Comment: You're using Prism ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For navigation, you want to register the views for navigation and then navigate to them.

```
// register the view
container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ViewA>();

// and some time later, show it in the region
regionManager.RequestNavigate( "TaxCalculatorRegion", "ViewA" );
```

If you register the view with a region instead, it will be automatically displayed in that region (View Discovery). Much more detailed info is available in the [Prism documentation](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Documentation/WPF/60-Navigation.md#prism-region-overview)...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, please see my updated code. The class implements the IModule and I don't have the 'RegisterTypeForNavigation' available here.

Comment: I understand that I can go back to the Bootstrapper class and go to ConfigureContainer() and use IUnityContainer, but I was wondering if I can move this whole registration to the module class

Comment: `RegisterTypeForNavigation` is an extension method, and lives in the `Prism.Unity` namespace (for Unity), you should be `using` that. Internally, it basically does `container.RegisterType(typeof(object), viewType, viewType.Name)`. And it's perfectly fine to have the container injected into your module definition class.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks!